# CSS/Bootstrap - weird <a> behaviour

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

My problem is, when i click on nav link "about", whitch is my one page index (top site) it changes color. When i click elswere its color comes back to normal. I am using bootstrap 3. 
Have You ever noticed something similar?

1. When i clik on 
   [image]
2. When i click elswere outsite 
   [image]

Comment: Sounds like the focus selector but you will need to post actual code for more help.

Comment: Does it have a `:focus` style? To test this, In chrome developer tools you can force an element to render as though it has focus by right clicking it in the Elements tab and clicking on :focus

Comment: I didn't set up :focus on my own, should i search for it in bootstrap.min.css?

Comment: Post or link to your code

Comment: I set up an :focus on this <a> with my own color and one problem is fixed but now the behaviour of this link is weird... After clicking it on the top of my page and then trying to scroll down it blinks once or twice and then scrolling down. First one or two mouse scrolls not working (<a> blinking instead)

Comment: Link to your site or fiddle? Scrolling shouldn't be affected by CSS in any way.

Comment: Let me just show You code for this matter only: https://jsfiddle.net/a8294dss/

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap has on links focus effect which means that after you click the link is still in focus and its style is changed.

You can override style as following:

```
a:focus {
   color: #default_color
}
```

where you can change `<a>` to any class which is on your main menu and color should be the one you are using for default style, in this case, white-ish

EDIT: I see you want to search for focus in bootstrap file. I would recommend overriding this in your main style file which should be loaded after bootstrap.

Comment: Yes i figured it out, but there is a new problem after using this solution: 
After clicking it on the top of my page and then trying to scroll down it blinks once or twice and then scrolling down. First one or two mouse scrolls not working (<a> blinking instead)

Comment: Post a link to your page or create a fiddle, it is hard to imagine what can be the problem without seeing it.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/a8294dss/

Comment: First two scrolls are not working because body animates over 500ms on click. Blinking is not happening in the fiddle.

Comment: The problem will be in js not in CSS and change of color on focus will not make difference, there must be something else going on. Try to update fiddle so it shows exact problem or post link to the whole site and I will be happy to see what's wrong.

Comment: Ok, I will publish my website and get back here to post it :)